# Google Maps with custom GEORss file

Tags: google-maps, httphandler, google-api, georss

Where would I need to host an xml file in order to use it in Google maps for GEORss ??

From google api docs...
var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20&lang=en-us&format=feed-georss');
georssLayer.setMap(map);

this seems to do a great job of creating the info popouts and everything...

It would seem i cannot have one locally...

So i guess i need an aspx or ashx to push the xml...but does it have to be web accessible?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be web accessible because Google converts the GeoRSS to KML on the server side:

"The Google Maps API supports the KML and GeoRSS data formats for displaying geographic information. These data formats are displayed on a map using a KmlLayer object, whose constructor takes the URL of a publicly accessible KML or GeoRSS file.

The Maps API converts the provided geographic XML data into a KML representation which is displayed on the map using a V3 tile overlay."

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers

If you are hosting a static XML file, you might use Amazon Web Service's Simple Storage Service: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/